# Definite Articles for Something Related

Tags: articles, definite-article

Definite articles are used for something already mentioned.

> Did you see Frozen 2? I liked the movie.

Is a definite article necessary in the following case?

> I form five groups. *The* leaders of **the** groups are active.

As the first sentence mentions "five groups," **the** may be necessary.

**Question 1**: Is *The* necessary even though I mention "leaders" for the first time?

**Question 2**: Is *The* necessary because followed by "of the groups?"

Comment: You are on the wrong site.  Please read the label. You should try English Language Learners.

Comment: My apologies for this silly question, but is this too easy or unfit here?

Answer (score 1):

> Definite articles are used for something already mentioned.

There are scads of uses of 'the' in English. This is not a comprehensive list.

> Question 1: Is The necessary even though I mention "leaders" for the first time?
>
> Question 2: Is The necessary because followed by "of the groups?"
>   definite-articles

No, the first 'the' is optional.